# UnrecognizedClientException error when authenticating on aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli, alpine-linux

When I pull a clean Alphine Linux Docker image, install `aws-cli` on it and try to authenticate myself with `aws ecr get-authorization-token --region eu-central-1` I keep getting the following error:

> An error occurred (**UnrecognizedClientException**) when calling the
>   GetAuthorizationToken operation: **The security token included in the**
>   **request is invalid**.

I've already checked the timezone which seem to be okay, and the command works properly on my local machine.

These are the commands I run to set up `aws-cli`:

`apk add --update python python-dev py-pip
pip install awscli --upgrade
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: You need to `export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=XXXXX`. How are you getting the access and secret keys?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR I got the keys after generating access keys in the IAM console. Is setting the `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` necessary? I thought this was only necessary if you don't use the permanent keys which I use. Also, it's not mentioned in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/setup-awscli.html.

Comment: Yep, it's not necessary. Have you looked at this forum question about using IAM roles: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=737198?

Comment: The keys I'm testing actually have got full Admin access, and the authentication with these exact keys works on my Macbook, so I'm sure it's got to be related to the setup somehow.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It was an access issue after all! Turns out that if you create a new IAM user with full admin access it can't by default access the ECR registry you created using a different account. Using the IAM credentials from that other account resolved the issue.

Comment: I'm facing this same error righ now when you found this solution?

Answer (score 32):

You don't have permission to access those resources until you get permission to `aws-cli`, for that you can use the below steps.

Log into your AWS account, click on your account name, select my security credentials, click on access keys and download the credentials

Open your `PowerShell` as administrator and follow the commands.

```
$ aws configure
$ AWS Access Key ID [****************E5TA]=xxxxxxxxxx
$ AWS Secret Access Key [****************7gNT]=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case, my `~/.aws/credentials` file had an old `aws_session_token` that was not updated by the `aws configure` CLI command.  Once I opened the file with `vi ~/.aws/credentials` and deleted the `aws_session_token` entry, I no longer encountered the `UnrecognizedClientException`.  I'm guessing that the AWS CLI first gives priority to the `aws_session_token` over the `aws access key id` and `aws secret access key` when running AWS CLI commands, if `aws_session_token` is present in the `~/.aws/credentials` file.

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me is:
on the first part of pipe add the param **--profile < your-profile-name >**
and after that in every ECR command you need to provide that parameter.

Comment: This worked for me. I was using the `aws ecr get-login-password` command for many years so far but then one day it started spitting an error message (UnrecognizedClientException). I simply added `--profile default` in the `aws ecr get-login-password` command and it started working again. Strange...

Answer (score 3):

Create a new account with `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess` permission.
Add this account to the `.credentials` file like this:

```
[ecr-user]
aws_access_key_id = XXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXX
```

Then next use following command:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --profile ecr-user
```

Answer (score 2):

My issue was caused by the fact that I had inactivated my access key in the AWS IAM Management Console earlier as part of an exercise I was doing.  Once I reactivated it, the problem was resolved.

(Make sure you're in the right AWS region, too.)

Answer (score 2):

I had same error message however I was using session based AWS access . The solution is to add all the keys given by AWS including session token.

```
aws_access_key_id="your-key-id"
aws_secret_access_key="your-secret-access-key"
aws_session_token="your-session-token"
```

add it into ~/.aws/credentials for profile you are using .

Answer (score 1):

Try running `echo $varname` to see if the environment variables are set correctly:

```bash
echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

If they are incorrectly set, run `unset varname`:

```bash
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
unset AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

Answer (score 1):

An update, --profile must be added, I solve this.

Comment: This answer is already given, your answer doesn't add any additional info.

Answer (score 1):

This stumped me for a while. Various flavours of exception. To finally get a fix, I wiped my aws home directory, and re-entered my `Access Key ID` and `Secret Access Key` from scratch.

```
rm -rf ~/.aws
aws configure
```

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, aws cli 2.11.21

Comment: That's a pretty straightforward answer. But I would add the following: go to AWS page > IAM > Users > Select your user > Scroll down to Access Key > Delete your old ones if they are expired > create a new one and copy the Secret ID and Secret Key to add at `aws configure` prompts

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue after following below:

1. Go to [AWS IAM Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home)
2. Generate credential in section "Access keys (access key ID and secret access key)"
3. Run command **aws configure** and set same downloaded credentials in Cdrive-User-directory.aws\credentials

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours , this is my conclusion :

> If you want to use `AWS_PROFILE` makes sure that the rest of AWS env vars are unset (NOT **empty** only ... MUST be **UNSET**).

```
profile=$AWS_PROFILE
unset $(printenv |grep AWS_ | cut -f1 -d"=");
export AWS_PROFILE=${profile};
```

Then :

```
  # with aws cli >= 1.x
  $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ${aws_region})

  # with aws cli >= 2.x
  registry=${aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.${aws_region}.amazonaws.com
  aws ecr get-login-password --region ${aws_region} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${registry}
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working for me. Out of sheer desperation, I copied the lines starting with `export` and posted them in the terminal and pressed enter.

Thereafter I wrote `aws configure` and filled in the details from https://MYCOMPANY.awsapps.com/start#/ >> Account >> Clicked "Command line or programmatic access".

Default region name: `eu-north-1`
Default output format: `text`

And then the login succeeded. Don't ask my why.

Answer (score 0):

open the file `~/.aws/credentials` (or `c:\Users\{user}\.aws\credentials` on Windows)

It might look something like the following:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXX
aws_session_token = XXXXX
```

Update the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` with new values and remove the `aws_session_token`. You can also update `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` via the `aws configure` command, but this doesn't remove the session token.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the region I wanted to use was not enabled. Addressed by enabling it at Account > AWS Regions -> enable (and wait patiently for some minutes).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error when trying to insert data into my DynamoDB table.

I took two steps:

1. Ran `aws configure` and set the access key, secret key and region.
2. Inserted access key, secret key, session token and region as arguments while creating `boto3` resource in my code.

Doing this solved the problem.