# UnrecognizedClientException when running `aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-3` from gitlab CI

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

I'm trying to run the following command from gitlab CI:

`$ aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-3`

Here's how the job in the .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this

```
publish-job:
  stage: publish
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws configure set default.region eu-west-3
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-3
```

And at the last step I get the following error:

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-3
An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I know there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488172/unrecognizedclientexception-error-when-authenticating-on-aws-cli) on stack overflow but I think it's not the same problem. In that question it's an issue that has to do with permissions. In my case I'm pretty sure it isn't for 2 reasons:

- I gave the user associated with the access key AdministratorAccess (temporarily in order to rule out the possibility that I'm dealing with an permissions issue)
- I performed the exact same steps (by copying and pasting) with docker and it works, so it's not the credentials. Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli:latest

RUN aws configure set aws_access_key_id THE_SAME_ACCESS_KEY_ID
RUN aws configure set aws_secret_access_key THE_SAME_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
RUN aws configure set default.region eu-west-3
RUN aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-3
```

Then I ran `$ docker build --progress=plain .` and the last step returned a hash

Any Idea why those steps give inconsistent results? And how to fix the CI?

Comment: The error means your access key or secret key is incorrect/invalid.

Comment: @jordanm I used the same access key in the Dockerfile and it works. Also, as pointed out in the stack overflow issue, the error message may mean that it's an permission issue. The error message seems like a generic response that can mean a few things.

Comment: Try calling `aws sts get-caller-identity` after configuring your credentials. This action requires no permissions and can serve as a basic test that your credentials are valid.

Comment: thanks @sytech. This command gave a more meaningful error message that allowed me to find the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I declared an AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variable that was preventing the cli from executing the command (even though I hardcoded the credentials at this stage). When I removed the environment variable, everything started working properly.